# Insoles rolling in when shoes are wet

Tags: hiking, mountaineering, trekking, shoes

I have a pair of shoes that are really not water-proof. But they are good for not-so-serious treks and have a superb grip over all sorts of terrain in India.

The only trouble I seem to have with them is that, after a certain use, the insole and the extra insole that I mostly need to have, they start rolling inside the shoes while descending. That get really annoying and sometimes if not fixed/re-positioned trouble one of the toes by random folds around it.

How do I deal with this?

Comment: Glue them in? :)

Comment: That didn't work yet.

Comment: I never experienced this, but I also was about to suggest to glue them. There IS a glue for everything.